# Set referer on react-native

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to set a referer value for all URL clicked in react-native project ? 
Of for some only ?

For example, a link component with an audio resource or anything else.

```
<Link source="http://www.someurl.tld/audio.mp3" />
```

Thanks